# Has anyone had trouble with Selenium tests results being inconsistent?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm currently using Selenium RC and JUnit to test some basic login and registration scenarios. The problem is that my tests don't always give the same results. Sometimes running them will be fine and the tests pass. Other times, they'll get stuck at certain points during the login/registration process and time out. I've been trying to debug this for a long time, but with no permanent success.

Is Selenium being flaky and has anyone else had similar issues?

Comment: Can't help much without code sample... this might be a timing issue but I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: Timing issue is what springs to mind for me too - this is where I've had things fail intermittently, Selenium trying to click on an element that hasn't been downloaded yet, page that hasn't opened, etc. Can you provide more detail about those certain points?

Answer (score 0):

I have used selenium for 3 years. Sometimes I have some strange situations but usually it is my wine or software problem. It's good practice to auto stop script or use screenshot function. To see that source of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when I use Ajax validation the results are inconsistent. I am testing using the Yii framework. I am generating random valid passwords, but from time to time Selenium goes too fast (!) for the Ajax to focus.

If I slow down the speed to 100 it tends to work about four out of five times. Any slower than that and the tests are agonizingly slow.

`$this->setSpeed(100);`